# Regex / Perl - Reverse sorting a hash table presenting white space as the first value in it even after regex

Tags: regex, perl

So i had yesterday posted a question about a regex regarding hyphens, and i proceeded to use this regex pattern:

```
$comparator =~ s/(?!-)[[:punct:]]//g;
```

And all was well. I was chomping the comparator as soon as it was read-in, applying that regex pattern to the strings in the file that were being read in, applying a loop like this:

```
foreach my $comparison(split /\s+/, $comparator)
```

and then adding those values to a hashtable with a %hash($word++). Next i proceeded to do a sorting comparison to print out the first 25 values from greatest to lowest occurence and used this

```
foreach my $key  (sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hashes)  {  if the value is less than 25, print them: }
```

It proceeds to print them, however my first value always is blank, so the output would be something like

First value,        occurs 5000 times

Second value,   cue, occurs 2300

Third value,    darling, occurs 1200

It seems to me that the hash is still counting whitespaces even though my regex pattern has told it to not count them. I have pretty much psudocode described my algorithm. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: That looks like a tab to me - Perl sometimes behaves weirdly with whitespace and regex. Have you tried `/[\s\t\r\n]+/`?

Comment: @remus - Would i make a new regex for that or would i add another regex pattern for $comparator right underneath the one i already one?

Comment: In your split where you have /s+/ - replace that.

Comment: (Speculating, dunno if it'll work)

Comment: @remus - It didn't work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From perldoc:

> As another special case, split emulates the default behavior of the
>   command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a literal
>   string composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or "\x20" ,
>   but not e.g. / / ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is
>   removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as
>   if it were /\s+/ ; in particular, this means that any contiguous
>   whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator.
>   However, this special treatment can be avoided by specifying the
>   pattern / / instead of the string " " , thereby allowing only a single
>   space character to be a separator. In earlier Perls this special case
>   was restricted to the use of a plain " " as the pattern argument to
>   split, in Perl 5.18.0 and later this special case is triggered by any
>   expression which evaluates as the simple string " " .

Your input string certainly contains multiple consecutive spaces, you'd better to split on `' '` instead of `\s+`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $str = ' abc def a    b ';
my @l;
@l = split' ',$str;
dump@l;
@l = split/ /,$str;
dump@l;
@l = split/\s+/,$str;
dump@l;
```

**output:**

```
("abc", "def", "a", "b")
("", "abc", "def", "a", "", "", "", "b")
("", "abc", "def", "a", "b")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$comparator` begins with spaces, the first element of the result of `split /\s+/, $comparator` will be an empty string. However, I can't explain why there are 5000 times.

Would you give a more realistic code snippet? There're some obvious errors in the codes. (To increase the counters, we should use `$hash{$comparison}++`. To sort from greatest to lowest, we use `$hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a}`. The hash should be `%hash` instead of `%hashes`.) I think they are not the working ones. I wonder if there's anything wrong not in the listed codes.